# How to access the swf file when playing in wpf web browser?

Tags: c#, wpf, actionscript-3, flash, webbrowser-control

Hi here I am using wpf web browser to play swf file and I just want to know how to find the current frame and total frame of a swf file.Then how to access the swf file like play/pause.

```
this.MainBrowser.Navigate(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\array-file-final020.swf");
```

this is the code I have used to play swf also I just want to know is it possible to communicate swf file with wpf web browser.

Comment: If you want to control SWF via C# code you need to have coded the SWF to use **external Interface** feature of AS3. See this **[tutorial](http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/communicate-betwen-c-and-an-embeded-flash-application/)** for a hint. Re-compile the SWF.

Comment: @VC.One ,Yeah you are right but it can be done only when we using axShockwaveFlash object.But I need to communicate using web browser.

Comment: close = axShockwaveFlash1.CallFunction("<invoke name=\"Head\" returntype=\"xml\"> <arguments><string>" + closeval + "</string></arguments></invoke>");

Comment: instead of axShockwaveFlash1.CallFunction what we have in web browser.